# Multiple app versions in managed publishing - Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I am using Google play store Managed publishing feature. I have multiple app versions as below in the "Changes ready to publish" state in the Google Play console. I would like to only publish v6.6.1 as staged rollout, but I wonder if v6.6.0 will also be published when I publish the releases. I dont want v6.6.0 to be pubished, would prefer if it could be deleted but there was no way to remove an approved release.

[image]

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @RohanTaneja - I had to publish both versions. If I didn't want 6.6.0 to be downloaded by users, then I had to set 6.6.1 to full rollout. If 6.6.1 is anything less than full rollout, users will get 6.6.0 if they are not selected to download 6.6.1. In short, I didn't find a way to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

I think this could be done by going to Google Play Console and select `App bundle explorer` from the left menu.

then chose the App version **6.6.0** click on `Upload new version`

[image]

you should upload a version that is identical to the version previous to **6.6.0** but with same **6.6.0**'s version code & same version name (6.6.0).
**Note:** I've never tried this before, but I noticed it in the new Google Play Console.

**Option 2:**

1. upload a new version that is identical to the version previous to **6.6.0** but with new version code (highest version code, higher than 6.6.1 version code) and version name 6.5.9 (for example)
2. submit it as `full roll-out`
3. upload a new version that is identical to the version previous to **6.6.1** but with new version code (highest version code, higher than 6.5.9 version code) and version name 6.6.1 with `Staged roll-out` = 1%